# Производительность Firebird Classic Server vs SuperServer

Tags: firebird

Не понимаю насчет Firebird, есть классическое описание отличия Classic от Superserver: https://firebirdsql.org/manual/ru/qsg15-classic-or-super-ru.html
Первый вроде как на процессах построен, второй на потоках.

Но простейший эксперимент - берем тяжелый запрос, который полностью загружает одно логическое ядро на достаточное время (несколько минут), общая загрузка процессора на моей машине 10% получается.

Запускаем этот запрос параллельно три раза.
На Classic общая нагрузка уходит в 30%, что логично.
На SuperServer загрузка по прежнему 10% и загружено 1 логическое ядро полностью, остальные простаивают.

Почему так происходит? Ощущение, что SuperServer "однопоточный", но так ведь не должно быть по логике...

P.S. Эксперименты проводил на Firebird 2.5.9 под windows 10.

Comment: У firebird в конфиге есть параметр `CpuAffinityMask`, и по умолчанию там указано использовать только первое ядро.

Comment: У каждого процесса внутри 1 и более потоков. Операционная система нагрузку между потоками распределяет по ядрам на своё усмотрение. Даже один поток может исполняться на нескольких ядрах (но есть нюансы). Ваши гипотезы безосновательны, по нагрузке на процессор невозможно определить количество потоков. В одном процессе могут быть тысячи активных потоков, но нагрузка общая может быть меньше, чем чем максимально возможная от одного потока.

Answer (score 0):

Да, суперсервер версии 2.5 использует только один поток на базу данных. Параметр CpuAffinityMask в файле конфигурации имеет умолчание 1 потому, что попытка использования нескольких ядер приводит к уменьшению производительности вследствие так называемого "thread bouncing" когда один поток перебрасывается операционной системой между ядрами с большими накладными расходами на этот процесс.

Настоящая многопоточность появилась в суперсервере только начиная с версии 3.

Текущая версия Firebird - 5.